# Stored procedure expects a parameter I am already passing in

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am trying to execute a stored procedure with this declaration:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getByName]
    @firstName varchar,
    @lastName varchar
AS
...
```

And I am calling in C# as follows:

```
public List<Person> GetPersonByName(string first, string last)
{
    var people = new List<Person>();
    var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConnString"].ConnectionString;
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.getByName",conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = first;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = last;
            conn.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                people = ReadPeopleData(reader);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    return people;
}
```

But I just get back this error:

> Procedure or function 'getByName' expects parameter '@firstName' which was not supplied.

**Update:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getEmployeesByName]
    @firstName varchar(50),
    @lastName varchar(50)
AS
...
```

and stating:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value
```

for both parameters, yet it continues to throw the exception.

Comment: Does `@lastName` work?

Comment: Try without the @. new SqlParameter("firstName"...

Comment: BTW: if you define your parameters as `varchar`, then you get a string of **exactly ONE character** length. Probably not what you want - right? **ALWAYS** define a length! Use `varchar(50)` or whatever makes sense....

Comment: those parameter of the sproc are not correctly defined.. VARCHAR with no length is a length of 1

Comment: hmm, i thought it would take max, let me try with a length specified.

edit: It appears the exception still occurs

Comment: @marc_s there is no commandtext property being assigned.

Comment: Also (after fixing length of varchar) Have you tried `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` instead of Add?

Comment: @marc_s sorry I meant I was not explicitly setting it after construction.  cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.getByName", connection) is being used

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Yes I have also tried it using AddWithValue("@first", first)

Comment: Please show complete code to reproduce. The issue is probably in something you have left out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have seen this issue occur many, many times in two common scenarios:

1. The value being assigned to the parameter is null (or Nothing in VB.Net). This is the .Net null, not the DB null (DBNull.Value) and this happens most commonly with strings.
2. The parameter being created is associated with the wrong command object. This commonly occurs when you have multiple command objects in the same class with similar names.

Please double-check the code to ensure that the string variable is not set to null and that the parameter is being added to the correct command.

**Update**

Based on the full updated code that was posted, the likely issue is 1 above.

To circumvent this problem in your code, add the following at the top of the method:

```
if (first == null) {
  first = "";
}
if (last == null) {
  last = "";
}
```

Comment: or just use null coalesce in the `Value =` portion.  Like `first ?? ""` and `last ?? ""`

Comment: Thank you!  When I was mocking GET requests to this API method I was using empty strings, but the default val() of the input fields was null instead of "".

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work:

```
SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[] { 
            new SqlParameter("@UserName",(object)userName ?? DBNull.Value),
            new SqlParameter("@Password",(object)password ?? DBNull.Value)
};
```

If parameter is NULL than replace it with DBNull Type using ?? Operator

Answer (score 0):

Please add CommandaType to SQLCommand.

e.g: scmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;